# Why do quarks and antiquarks tend to bond in groups in which the number of quarks minus the number of antiquarks is divisible by 3?

Tags: quarks, confinement, mesons, baryons, hadron-dynamics

Why do quarks and antiquarks tend to bond in groups with [quark number](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/quark+number) a multiple of 3?

I understand why they might in bond in groups of three to create a net charge of zero (i.e. neutrons), but I don't understand why they form protons and not, for example, commonly form in groups of four. I have done background research on this question, and did not find any information. The wikipedia article on baryons (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon) was not helpful either.

To summarize, why are mesons and baryons more common than other hadrons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Anything made of quarks must have net color neutrality.*

Quarks come in the following 'colors': **red**, **blue**, and **green**. All three combine to be color neutral

[image: RGB three-way Venn diagram. Where all three colors overlap there is white ("color neutral")]

Antiquarks come in the following 'colors': **antired**, **antiblue**, and **antigreen**. All three combine to be color neutral

[image: Antiquark color three-way Venn diagram. Where all three colors overlap there is black ("color neutral")]

Colors and their anticolors combine to be color neutral (i.e. **red** and **antired** combine to be color neutral)

Hence...

- One quark ***cannot*** be color neutral
- Two quarks ***cannot*** be color neutral
- One quark and one antiquark ***can*** be color neutral [*meson*]
- 3 quarks ***can*** be color neutral [*baryon*]
- Two quarks and two antiquarks ***can*** be color neutral [*tetraquark*]
- 4 quarks and one antiquark ***can*** be color neutral (three colors + color/anticolor) [*pentaquark*]

You can see that singular quarks and diquarks are not possible and that baryons and mesons are simpler in structure, hence, more common.

Answer (score 13):

Each quark $q$ and antiquark $\bar{q}$ transform in the [fundamental representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_representation) ${\bf 3}$ and [antifundamental representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antifundamental_representation) $\bar{\bf 3}$ of the color group $SU(3)_C$, respectively.

However, a [hadron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadron) has to be a color singlet ${\bf 1}$, due to [color confinement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement).

In particular the [center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(group_theory))
$$\mathbb{Z}_3~:=~\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}~=~\{1,e^{\pm 2\pi i/3}\} ~\subseteq ~SU(3)_C$$ of the color group $SU(3)_C$ should be in a [trivial representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_representation) of the [cyclic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) $\mathbb{Z}_3$. This precisely happens if the [quark number](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/quark+number) is a multiple of 3. This answers OP's title question.

*Examples:*

- A single quark $q$ transforms in the fundamental representation ${\bf 3}$ of $SU(3)_C$, and is hence *not* allowed. See also related Phys.SE post [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45514/2451).
- A [diquark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diquark) $qq$ belongs to the tensor representation ${\bf 3}^{\otimes 2}:={\bf 3}\otimes{\bf 3}\cong\bar{\bf 3}\oplus{\bf 6}_S$, which we have decomposed in [irreps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation) of $SU(3)_C$. This contains no singlet ${\bf 1}$, and is hence *not* allowed. See also related Phys.SE posts [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10403/2451) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167680/2451) about $SU(3)$ tensor representations.
- In a [meson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson), the quark-antiquark-pair $q\bar{q}$ belongs to ${\bf 3}\otimes\bar{\bf 3}\cong{\bf 1}\oplus{\bf 8}_M$, which contains a singlet ${\bf 1}$, and is hence allowed.
- The third tensor product is ${\bf 3}^{\otimes 3}={\bf 3}\otimes{\bf 3}\otimes{\bf 3}\cong {\bf 1}\oplus 2\cdot{\bf 8}_M\oplus{\bf 10}_S$. In a [baryon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon), the three quarks $qqq$ form a totally antisymmetric representation $\wedge^3 {\bf 3}\cong {\bf 1}$ of $SU(3)_C$, which is isomorphic to a singlet ${\bf 1}$, and is hence allowed. See also related Phys.SE post [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1534/2451). The lightest baryon, the [proton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton), is stable in the [standard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) due to [baryon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_number)/quark number conservation. (However, see the hypothetical [proton decay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay).)
- The tensor product ${\bf 3}\otimes{\bf 3}\otimes\bar{\bf 3}\cong 2\cdot{\bf 3}\oplus {\bf 6}_M\oplus {\bf 15}_M$ contains no singlet ${\bf 1}$, so the combination $qq\bar{q}$ is *not* allowed.
- The fourth tensor product is ${\bf 3}^{\otimes 4}\cong 3\cdot{\bf 3}\oplus 2\cdot{\bf 6}_M\oplus 3\cdot{\bf 15}_M\oplus{\bf 15}_S$. This contains no singlet ${\bf 1}$, so four quarks $qqqq$ are *not* allowed.
- A "molecule" of mesons and baryons, such e.g. a [tetraquark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetraquark) $q\bar{q}q\bar{q}$ or a [pentaquark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentaquark) $qqqq\bar{q}$, is also allowed, but is obviously heavier. See also related Phys.SE posts [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33578/2451), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107990/2451), and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195310/2451).

TL;DR: The number of quarks minus the number of antiquarks should be divisible by 3.

References:

1. G. 't Hooft, [*Introduction to Lie Groups in Physics*](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/%7Ehooft101/lectures/lieg.html), lecture notes, chapter 10. The pdf file is available [here](http://www.phys.uu.nl/%7Ethooft/lectures/lieg07.pdf).

Comment: What is meant by the subscripts $M$ and $S$?

Comment: $S$=totally symmetric (Young tableaux with only one row); $M$=mixed symmetry (Young tableaux with more than one row and more than one column); For $SU(3)$ there is effectively only one totally antisymmetric Young tableaux (two boxes in a column): $\wedge^2 {\bf 3}\cong\bar{\bf 3}$.