# Permitted bound states in extended QCD color group $SU(4)$

Tags: group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, confinement, hadron-dynamics

I'm very much curious about the possible quark combinations to form bound states in $SU(4)$ QCD.
We already know Wilson has proven that only colorless combinations can arise in $SU(3)$ of these formats: $q\bar{q}$, $qqq$, tetra quarks and penta quarks.
I guess in $SU(4)$ one can only find $q\bar{q}$ and $qqqq$ and combinations of these two.
Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is still the same: A [hadron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadron) has to be a color singlet ${\bf 1}$ under the $SU(N)_C$ color gauge group, due to [color confinement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement).

- A single quark $q$ transforms in the fundamental representation ${\bf N}$ of $SU(N)_C$, and is hence *not* allowed since $N>1$.
- In a [meson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson), the quark-antiquark-pair $q\bar{q}$ belongs to ${\bf N}\otimes\bar{\bf N}\cong{\bf 1}\oplus({\bf N^2\!-\!1})_{\rm Adj}$, which contains a singlet ${\bf 1}$, and is hence allowed.
- In a [baryon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon), the $N$ quarks $\overbrace{qq\ldots q}^{N\text{ times}}$ form a totally antisymmetric representation $\wedge^N {\bf N}\cong {\bf 1}$ of $SU(N)_C$, which is isomorphic to a singlet ${\bf 1}$, and is hence allowed.

As one can see the number of quarks minus the number of anti-quarks should be divisible by $N$. For $N=3$, see also my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/219725/2451).

Answer (score 1):

In fact yes, a simple way to get all possible states is by the following argument: quarks belong to the fundamental representation of the color group, and to them one can assign the upper index $q^{i}$, the antiquarks belong to the antifundamental representation, and to them we assign the lower index $\bar{q}_i$. Also there is a Levi-Civita symbol $\varepsilon^{i_1 \ldots i_N}$  ($N$ being the number of colors). The asymptotic states in QCD are color singlets $-$ so to get all possible states, you should contract all indices with each other in some way.

As for quark-antiquark pair you form a singlet by:
$$
\bar{q}_i q^{i} \,,
$$Which means taking the trace in color space. And baryons (antibaryons) correspond to:
$$
\varepsilon_{i_1 \ldots i_N} q^{i_1} \ldots q^{i_N} \,,\qquad
\varepsilon^{i_1 \ldots i_N} \bar{q}_{i_1} \ldots \bar{q}_{i_N}
\,.$$