# Can a baryon consist of two quarks and an antiquark? Or a pentaquark be made of three quarks and two antiquarks?

Tags: quarks, confinement, baryons, hadron-dynamics, pentaquarks

I suspect these particles exist, but are extremely short-lived, even compared to other unstable, exotic particles...

Comment: Not color neutral. So they will be canceled.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219710/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Besides 'color neutrality', I've heard about the importance of 'antisymmetry' and 'singlet representation' in making a stable (or at least semi-stable) composite quark particle...